# How to show Title Name on Top Navigation bar instead of Hamburger icon in xamarin forms shell

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin

I'm creating Tab bar using xamarin forms shell. I never add the flyout, but, I've no idea why the hamburger menu appear on the top navigation bar.
how can i disappear it and it should show the tab bar title on the top navigation bar.

[image] [image]

I did add this: `FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"`
but, it's doesn't work.

```
    <TabBar >
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Home}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="CashBack" Icon="cashback.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Cashback}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="My Point" Icon="mypoint.png">
            <ShellContent Title="My Point"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MyPoint}"/>
            <ShellContent Title="History" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate point:PointHistory}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Me" Icon="me.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Me}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: Seems like, it's not related to `Flyout`. You can try to disable the navigation bar using `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` Also look at this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/144405/hamburger-menu-and-bottom-bar-navigation-in-same-main-master-page)

Comment: NO, I need the navigation bar to be appear. I really have no idea why this hamburger appear on the navigation bar.

Comment: Are you using master-detail page inside tab bar somewhere? Or maybe have a popup menu?

Comment: no, i did not, my project was created from blank. I just uploaded one image, you can have a view. it really look like flyout (since i'm using shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue at **Xamarin.Forms 4.2 version**, I have report this bug for Microsoft team.

Now there are two ways to resolve this issue.

1. You can use **Xamarin.Forms version 4.1**, then it works fine.
2. You can use **Xamarin.Forms version 3.6**, then following the steps:

Please take a look RouteHost="companyname.com"(package name) RouteScheme="app" Route="shellsample"(solution name)

```
 <ShellItem>
    <ShellSection Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </ShellSection>
    <ShellSection Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </ShellSection>
</ShellItem>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.com/2019/02/xamarin-month-fall-in-love-with.html

Comment: after i upgrade the xamarin.forms to 4.2.0.778463. it works fine, means it is the bugs of microsoft, not my code issue.